# Evaluating code but suppressing output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a chuck

````
 ```{r}
Item <- melt(Item)
```
````

Which creates an output :

```
   ## Using as id variables
```

How do I evaluate the code but suppress this output.

Answer (score 1):

```
{r, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
Item <- melt(Item)
```

Details are documented here : https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf